# Detect which properties changed on an Entity Framework EntityObject

Tags: .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I want to read changes within an `EntityObject` for inclusion in a report.

For example:

> **Name:** <strike>Before</strike> After
>
> **Location:** <strike>Before</strike> After

Is there a generic way to do this? I'm using EF4 with default entity class generation (not POCO).

These entities will be attached, so they should be being tracked for changes.  I cannot see a means to do this via the `IEntityWithChangeTracker` interface.

Traversing navigation properties would be nice, but it'd be enough of a win to just report upon changed primitive properties.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can retrieve `ObjectStateEntry` for your entity and check contents of `CurrentValues` and `OriginalValues`. Try this (untested):

```
ObjectStateEntry entry = objectContext.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntry(entity);
foreach (string property in entry.GetModifiedProperties()) {
    object oldValue = entry.OriginalValues[property];
    object newValue = entry.CurrentValues[property];
}
```

This will not handle navigation properties and I'm not sure how it would work with complex types.

Comment: Just tested this out on some `string` properties and it worked a charm. I do have some complex types and navigation properties, so will try that out later and post here if I find anything useful. Thanks very much Ladislav.

Comment: @Ladislav How would one achieve this using EF6 & DbContext? BTW - Your handle breaks the autocomplete on the comment box.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Ladislav Mrnka's suggestion: Not really generic, but at least a *possible* solution: [Code Generation and T4 Text Templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb126445.aspx). This allows you to add your own custom logic to each entity when the models are generated.

In your case, you could implement the needed traversing functionality to check the navigation properties.

Comment: T4 templating is efinitely worth mentioning here for completeness, but in my case at least it seems that using the existing API will suffice, and be generally easier/safer.